# Why Identity Mapping is not Measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Letting $C$ denote the set of subsets of the unit interval $[0,1]$ which are either countable or having countable complement, and letting $\mu$ denote the counting measure on $C$, why is it that the identity mapping $f:x\mapsto x$ is not $C$-measurable? When the $\sigma$-algebra is the same in the domain and codomain, shouldn't the identity mapping always be measurable?

Comment: As you said, the identity map from a measure space to itself is measurable: measurable sets pull back to themselves. Are you sure the source and target of $f$ are equipped with the same $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: I think '$C$- measurable' is supposed to mean that the inverse image of any Borel set belongs to $C$, no that inverse image of any set in $C$ belongs to $C$. This is how measurability of real valued functions is usually understood.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since the sigma-algebras in the domain and co-domain agree we have, if $\Sigma \equiv \{A \subset [0,1] \colon A$ or $A^c$ is countable$\}$, then $id^{-1}(A) = A \in \Sigma$ for all $A \in \Sigma$. So $id$ is surely measurable. However, if you make changes to one of the sigma-algebras, let's say we set the sigma algebra of the co-domain to $\Sigma=\{\emptyset, [0,1/2],(1/2,1],[0,1]\}$. Then clearly $id^{-1}((1/2,1])=(1/2,1]$ is itself not countable, nor is its complement, so in that case $id$ is not measurable.